# Dynamic programming with less decision variables than states

Tags: optimization, dynamic-programming

I'm trying to solve a dynamic programming problem with $n$ (continuous) state variables and only $1$ (continuous) decision variable, which affects all the states. For $n=1$ this is a standard problem and I can compute the FOC easily. For larger $n$, and even for $n=2$, the same process fails and I cannot seems to get a formula for the FOC.
Is there an inherent problem with such a problem, or am I doing something wrong? Has anyone encountered a similar example?

To be more precise, here is my model:

$s\in \mathbf{R}^{n}$ is a state vector, $f:\mathbf{R}\times\mathbf{R}^n\to\mathbf{R}$ is the one-stage payoff function and $\beta\in (0,1)$ is the discount factor.
The decision maker chooses $x\in [0,1]$ and the next state is determined by some deterministic transition function $g:\mathbf{R}\times\mathbf{R}^n\to\mathbf{R}^n$.
Formally, the optimization problem is

$$V(s)=\max\limits_{x\in[0,1]} f(x,s)+\beta V(g(x,s)) $$

And I wish to find the first-order condition that connects $x_t,x_{t+1}$ and $s_{t}$ in terms of $f,g$ and their derivatives.

Thanks!

Comment: What about $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \beta \sum_{i}{\frac{\partial V}{\partial g_i}\frac{\partial g_i}{\partial x}} = 0$?

Comment: That's one of the equations, but $V$ is an unknown value function so it should be expressed in other terms and that's where I struggle.